# How can I handle a huge XML file using SimpleXML but to prevent memory and performance problems?

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I am trying to avoid XMLReader for an app I build that has a huge XML file.
SimpleXML is easy to write and I was wondering if there is any way to successfully handle it (memory and performance issues) in a quite busy server.
What I will do, is to echo some data from that XML mainly from a search form.

Comment: In short: No way, because `simpleXML` (as well as any other document based parser like DOM) always reads the _entire_ XML file while loading. Have a look at XMLReader (its stream-based).

Comment: Why are you trying to avoid XMLReader ? And why are you parsing this XML ? Just for some nodes ? SimpleXML and XMLReader have different goals and performances, but can achieve the same things.

Comment: I might have missunderstood some terms. I am trying to avoid it because I can't find many examples to help me out. So reading your comments I guess I have to go with XMLReader then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, if you really want to do this without XMLReader, here's what you could do.

Use fopen to open and read N number of bytes of that file.

Fix the ending  : (That's the tough part but it's perfectly doable)
You do it by closing anything left unclosed and also if needed backtracking if you happen to be in the middle of some text.

When that XML chunk is finally valid you can parse it with simplexmL.

Process that chunk or save it in its separate XML file
and create another chunk ...until you have all of them.

Obviously if your XML is complex this might get a little painful.

Summary :
By creating your own custom/dirt-cheap xml parser/fixer you can split a huge XML file into multiple smaller files.

Comment: Hi there, this is something I tried with XML Parser (you can see it here at the very end http://www.ustrem.org/en/articles/large-xml-files-in-php-en/ ). What I tested is a 120mb file with XML Parser and SimpleXML, outputting the same things. I did a memory test and found that SimpleXML was lower in memory and incredibly faster. As I read, I was expecting different results but this is what I see.

Answer (score 1):

If your file is mostly a lot of similar nodes, like a big list of books where the number of books is large but the book record itself is small, you could use a variation of smaura's answer by using XMLReader to walk through each node, then convert the node to an XML string and pass it to SimpleXML.   That way, you're using a streaming solution for the big list, but once you get each record you get the benefits of easily accessing the record with SimpleXML.